# Select area/rectangle in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to select a region in an HTML5 page via the mouse.

I'm then going to interact with the elements within that region.

There MUST be an easy way to do it but I couldn't find anything off the shelf..

The jquery UI selection didn't work unfortunately because it seems to only support one parent element.

Is there anything off the shelf to draw a transparent div over a region with a dashed outline?

Or an easy implementation.  I could probably spend a couple of hours and bang something out but I'm surprised there's nothing that allows me to do it in 5 minutes.

Comment: what you have tried? Post Code

Answer (score 46):

Seems simple enough…

Create a div that's initially hidden:

```
<div id="div" hidden></div>
```

Style it:

```css
#div {
    border: 1px dotted #000;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And the JS:

```
var div = document.getElementById('div'), x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0;
function reCalc() { //This will restyle the div
    var x3 = Math.min(x1,x2); //Smaller X
    var x4 = Math.max(x1,x2); //Larger X
    var y3 = Math.min(y1,y2); //Smaller Y
    var y4 = Math.max(y1,y2); //Larger Y
    div.style.left = x3 + 'px';
    div.style.top = y3 + 'px';
    div.style.width = x4 - x3 + 'px';
    div.style.height = y4 - y3 + 'px';
}
onmousedown = function(e) {
    div.hidden = 0; //Unhide the div
    x1 = e.clientX; //Set the initial X
    y1 = e.clientY; //Set the initial Y
    reCalc();
};
onmousemove = function(e) {
    x2 = e.clientX; //Update the current position X
    y2 = e.clientY; //Update the current position Y
    reCalc();
};
onmouseup = function(e) {
    div.hidden = 1; //Hide the div
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jLqHv/

Comment: Is `hidden` really a boolean attribute on `<div>`s?

Comment: @false [Yup.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#hidden) The fiddle works, doesn't it?

Comment: I wouldn’t know; jsFiddle hasn’t worked for me for a while. Anyways, cool! `hidden` seems like a useful addition.

Comment: @minitech HTML5 defines that attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#hidden

Comment: I know this topic is kinda old but I found it while looking for the same thing, do you have any idea how I can detect input elements that are under the selected area ?

Comment: @KiJéy You can loop thru the inputs and use [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) with some math to find the elements in the selected rect.

Comment: @bjb568 it has to be pageX and pageY otherwise after scrolling it wont work

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but, this gives me a way to do what I wanted. Thank you so much for posting this code snippet.

Comment: This is good and I know its old post but anyway to restrict selection in certain area? For ex. I don't want user to be able to select outside an <div>

Comment: Here's the revised code from this example with a container and start, stop, select, and remove events. https://github.com/tjmoses/selection-drag/blob/master/src/selection.ts

Answer (score 17):

I've created a library for exactly this purpose:
https://github.com/Simonwep/selection

There's currently full desktop and mobile / touch support as well as auto-scroll functionality as you know from your file explorer :)

Comment: This is just too good @Simon! Thank you so much for this! :D

Comment: Wow! This looks awesome! Excited to try it :)